# Why isn't mobile detection enabled working in my Django template?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, templates, mobile

I'm using Django and Python 3.7. I would like to display some table data slightly differently on mobile browsers, so I formatted my table view template like this:

```
{% if request.user_agent.is_mobile %}
    <td align="center"><a href="{{ articlestat.article.mobile_path }}" target="_blank">{{ articlestat.hits|floatformat:"0" }}</a></td>
{% else %}
    <td align="center"><h2><a href="{{ articlestat.article.path }}" target="_blank">{{ articlestat.hits|floatformat:"0" }}</a></h2></td>
{% endif %}
```

However after deploying and restarting my server, viewing this on a mobile browser still shows the non-mobile branch. Is there something else I need to do to activate mobile detection? My phone is an Android LG, viewing on a Chrome browser if that matters.

**Edit:** I'm using the "django-user-agents" extension, found here -- https://github.com/selwin/django-user_agents. In truth, I'm open to any solution that can accurately detect mobile browsers, this just happened to be the first one taht came up on Google.

Comment: Did you also try it with other mobile devices? Or just tested it with your browser by setting different User-Agents?
-> If your mobile-code still doesn't show up, check the content of `request`-object and (if present) `request.user_agent`, maybe that'll give you some more information, e.g. maybe you just simply forgot the middleware or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try the [Template Filters](https://github.com/selwin/django-user_agents#template-usage)? You can use them by doing the following:

```
{% load user_agents %}

{% if request|is_mobile %}
    Mobile device stuff...
{% endif %}
```

Otherwise, you should try just entering `{{ request|is_mobile }}` into your template and seeing what it outputs.

Another option you have is using CSS to target the `divs`, and hide/show them based on screen size. It isn't exact, but it is highly customizable. Example:

**html**

```
<td class="td-desktop" align="center"><h2><a href="{{ articlestat.article.path }}" target="_blank">{{ articlestat.hits|floatformat:"0" }}</a></h2></td>
<td class="td-mobile" align="center"><a href="{{ articlestat.article.mobile_path }}" target="_blank">{{ articlestat.hits|floatformat:"0" }}</a></td>
```

**css**

```
.td-mobile {
    display: none;
}
@media (max-width:768px)  {
    .td-desktop {
        display: none;
    }
    .td-mobile {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Comment: What extra library do I need to install to get this to work?  I'm getting the error, "'user_agents' is not a registered tag library" when I add the "{% load user_agents %}" line, even thogh I have "django-user-agents==0.3.2" as a part of my project.

Comment: Its part of the same package, which means it wasnt installed correctly. Try running “pip install pyyaml ua-parser user-agents”, and then add “django-user-agents” to your INSTALLED_APPS. Also, make sure to add everything specified here: https://github.com/selwin/django-user_agents/blob/master/README.rst

Comment: So I installed all the modules with Pip but after adding "django-user-agents" to my installed apps, I get the error, "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django-user-agents'" when I restart my application and try to visit the page in question.

Comment: Oh hey it was actually "django_user_agents'" and now I don't get the error.  Going to run a few more tests but this is looking real good.

Comment: @Dave my bad about the typo! Let me know how it goes